# How to change /home size

Tags: linux, centos6, partition

This server is running CentOS 6.5 minimal and comes equiped with two 3TB HDD.  `df -h` shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2       1008G  933M  956G   1% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md1        496M   32M  439M   7% /boot
/dev/md3        1.7T  196M  1.6T   1% /home
```

I need to increase my /home partition to 2.5T

How to reduce /dev/md2   and increase /dev/md3

My server is new with no data.

Comment: If the server is brand new, I recommend to just reinstall the OS and size the volumes in a way that you need. This is much easier than doing the various resize operations required to do what you want. RAID0 is not per se bad, but it should only be used in cirumstances where you need fast disks and can live with the total data loss you will experience when one of the disks fail. Usually, this excludes any kind of system and data volume.

Comment: I installed again but server partion is 2T max I need 2.5T.

Comment: When creating the partition table, don't use MBR, but GPT instead.

Comment: I have installed from rescue disk from hetzner servers. is there a config file for MBR GPT?

Comment: Sorry, can't comment on that, I never used them. According to http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installimage/en#Why_can.27t_I_create_partitions_larger_than_2_TiB.3F, you might have to select to use GRUB2 as loader at some point.

Comment: I think you will need to use CentOS 7 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MBR has a max 2TB size limit.  You need to format the partition to GPT, which supports larger partition sizes (depending on your sector size, it could go well beyond TB, PB, and EB).

If you're doing the base install with the CentOS 6.5; you need to change the partition from MBR to GPT before you define the partitions or install the OS. You can do this manually by bringing up a second terminal (CTL+SHIFT+F1), loading GParted and manually resizing the drives, then going back to the main terminal (CTL+SHIFT+BACKSPACE), and continuing your install like normal.